# Home Button Disappearing from IOS Simulators

Tags: ios-simulator

When I started programming this evening, the home button and frame was visible on all the iPhone similators.

As I worked through the evening, the buttons started disappearing, one-by-one from all the simulators.

I rebooted and some buttons came back, leaving me with this (yes=button shows):

```
iPhone Retina 3-1/2 - Yes
iPhone Retina - No
iPhone Retina 64 - yes
iPad - Yes
iPad Retina - No
iPad Retina 64 - No
```

How can I get them all to behave the same way?

Answer (score 0):

If Button is not there Then Use **cmd+shift+h** It will automatically take you to the **home screen**.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your scale (window->scale) is set to 100%. At 75% and 50% the frame and buttons are hidden.

Also, you can change these using command+1,2,3

Comment: All are at 100%. No button. It's weird that some have the button others do no.